# Module to send bash command to system

Tags: linux, bash, module, kernel-module

I have to write a module that sends a command to the system.

For example: The "ls" command, as you know, is a common bash command.

Since I am new at this module thing, I need some help.

Comment: `type ls => ls is hashed (/bin/ls)` shows, that it is not a shell build-in, but an external program. What do you mean with `send a command to the system`? And: Is it homework? "I have to ..." sounds so.

Comment: no it is not homework of course. i think that's because of my bad english.

Comment: the main idea is that i want to run the commands like ls,cd,cat from my module. I dont know if i explain clearly

Comment: I don't see the connection from command (which is a separate program, in the case of `ls`) to bash to module. `ls` is not a `bash command`, it's a program and can be invoked from bash as every other program, and can be invoked from zsh or dash as well. So do you want to call just a program from a module, or is there some closer connection to bash? `cd` in contrast **is** a bash build-in. Why do you want to do it in a module? Btw.: Do you mean `kernel module` by `module`?

Comment: yes, i mean kernel module. I want to start my application which is written in qt from my module. That is all i want to do. I start my app with "./path_to_app/app -qws" (without quotes). I want my module to execute this command.

Comment: Okay, things slowly get clearer. Now what's your problem? Are you new to C too? Did you write a program which starts your qt-app from a normal program? What have you tried so far? How did it fail?

Comment: I think i need a lot more research before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `ls` is no bash builtin command.

You can call any program (for example `ls`) with the complete path (`/usr/bin/ls`).

Comment: The OP didn't say that it's a bash built-in command, just that it's a "common bash command", presumably meaning that it's commonly invoked from bash.  Note that the question is about kernel modules; I don't know that `/usr/bin/ls` is enough to do that (but I could be wrong).

Comment: the main idea is that i want to run the commands like ls,cd,cat from my module. I dont know if i explain clearly